# How to use multiple Program classes in xUnit test project with WebApplicationFactory

Tags: .net-core, xunit

I want to use WebApplicationFactory to create hosts for my tests, but I want to create 2 Web Application Factories for two projects I refereed in single XUnit test project.

When I refer only one project then everything is working fine.

But when I refer two projects, it seems that WebApplicationFactory cant recognize which Program class I want to use.

My goal is to have 2 classes for 2 dummy apps (like on the screen) in a single XUnit test project.

It seems that I cant precise which Program class I want to use in WebApplicationFactory with using statement.

Is it possible to create 2 Web Application Factories for different Pragram classes in one XUnit project, and if yes, then how to do this?

**SOLVED THIS MYSELF** - it seems that XUnit does not recognize that Program class in .NET6 is in a file where there is no namespace declaration. The solution is to create separate file with namespace declaration and 'public partial class Program{ }' inside. Then you are able to use full path in WebApplicationFactory<TestedProjectNamespace.Program>

[How I`d like it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ8E7.png)

Comment: There shouldn't be an issue in doing this. If it's just struggling in recognising which Program class to use, why not put it's full path including namespaces etc?

Comment: I tried this, WebApplicationFactory<ProjectNamespace.Program> gives compilation error 'cannot resolve symbol'. It seems like it cannot find this class.

Comment: If you're using .net 6, you can modify the csproj file where your program file is and add the "InternalsVisibleTo" property. This is also Microsoft's recommendation as found here; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0
 That's probably the reason that XUnit can't find it

Comment: @scottdavidwalker Hi, thanks, I did it, the reason was different, I`ve edited my question and added solution for future reference

Comment: @jwtk can you please provide code snippet of your solution?

Comment: @killswitch The solution is to create separate file with namespace declaration and 'public partial class Program{ }' inside. Thats it, WebApplicationFactory will then be able to use it.