# How to get access_token for integration tests for passing [Authorize] tag? ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, integration-testing, identityserver4, xunit

I have a WebAPI on ASP.NET and IdentityServer4 project for authorization, registration and all of this stuff. So, right now i creating integration tests for this API and i cant reach API methods that have an [Authorize] tag and i get Unauthoruzed:401 exception on test.
For example WebAPI method:

```
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ChangePasswordResponse), 200)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ChangePasswordResponse), 400)]
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost("change-password")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ChangePasswordResponse>> ChangePassword([FromBody] ChangePasswordRequest request)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("***");
        var model = _mapper.Map<ChangePasswordModel>(request);
        var response = await _userAccountService.ChangePassword(model);
        if (response == null)
            return BadRequest(response);
        return Ok(response);
    }
```

And test is:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task ChangePassword_Returns200Response()
    {
        // Arrange;
        var model = new ChangePasswordRequest
        {
            Email = StudentConsts.Email,
            CurrentPassword = StudentConsts.Password,
            NewPassword = StudentConsts.NewPassword
        };

        var request = _sutDataHelper.GenerateRequestFromModel(model);
        
        // Act
        var response = await _client.PostAsync("accounts/change-password", request);
        var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var content = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ChangePasswordResponse>(responseContent);

        // Asserts
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        content.Email.Should().Be(model.Email);
        content.UserName.Should().Be(StudentConsts.UserName);
    }
```

Integration tests is created with `IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory>` and i dont put any code for authentication from WebAPI but when i put this code from WebAPI i getting errors like: `SchemeAlreadyExists: Identity.Application` or `SchemeAlreadyExists: Bearer`

Services setup code for authorization:

```
services
            .AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole<Guid>>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
            .AddUserManager<UserManager<User>>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddJwtBearer(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = "HERE IS IDENTITYSERVER4 SERVICE URL";
                options.Authority = "HERE IS IDENTITYSERVER4 SERVICE URL";
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    RequireExpirationTime = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
                options.Audience = "api";
            });
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(AppScopes.OpenId, policy => policy.RequireClaim("scope", AppScopes.OpenId));
            options.AddPolicy(AppScopes.Profile, policy => policy.RequireClaim("scope", AppScopes.Profile));
            options.AddPolicy(AppScopes.Email, policy => policy.RequireClaim("scope", AppScopes.Email));
            ...
        });
```

When i add another AnotherWebApplicationFactory file IDE just telling me that Program class is exists in WebAPI and IS4 project and maybe that means that i cant create 2 project at the same time for integration tests for getting access_token from http://host:00/connect/token identityserver4 link.
Also i cant just hard code fake access_token from other user i register in WebAPI by yourself cuz he is telling me that token not allowed or something like this. I just started learning integration tests and getting stack on authorization.

Comment: Read this please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72076684/how-to-use-multiple-program-classes-in-xunit-test-project-with-webapplicationfac

Comment: Just create a service to generate a token and check expiry always to generate a new token via help of token service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED BY THIS SOLUTION:
https://question-it.com/questions/418799/kak-otkljuchit-vkljuchit-autentifikatsiju-vo-vremja-vypolnenija-v-aspnet-core-22

Clearly added policies to services setup in integration tests with AuthRequirement and AuthRequirementHandler.

Services Setup:

```
            services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, MaintenanceModeDisabledOrAuthenticatedUserRequirementHandler>();

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .AddRequirements(new MaintenanceModeDisabledOrAuthenticatedUserRequirement())
                    .Build();

                options.AddPolicy(AppScopes.OpenId, builder => builder
                    .AddRequirements(new MaintenanceModeDisabledOrAuthenticatedUserRequirement()));
                options.AddPolicy(AppScopes.Profile, builder => builder
                    .AddRequirements(new MaintenanceModeDisabledOrAuthenticatedUserRequirement()));
                options.AddPolicy(AppScopes.Email, builder => builder
                    .AddRequirements(new MaintenanceModeDisabledOrAuthenticatedUserRequirement()));
            });
```

AuthRequirement:

```
public class MaintenanceModeDisabledOrAuthenticatedUserRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{ }
```

AuthRequirementHandler:

```
public class MaintenanceModeDisabledOrAuthenticatedUserRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MaintenanceModeDisabledOrAuthenticatedUserRequirement>
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MaintenanceModeDisabledOrAuthenticatedUserRequirement requirement)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Hope you solved your problem!